# Upper bound complexity for a tree's particular property

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, binary-trees

I want to determine if

> in a given binary tree whose nodes are integers, left subtree's
>   (let's call it L) nodes are multiples of (at least one) right
>   subtree's (R) node(s).

I only require that every integer in L must be a divisor of some number in R, but not the reverse (for every number in R, it is a multiple of some number in L).

Speaking with other words: if $a$ is in L, then it is multiple of at least a number in R. (e.g. $R=\{4\}$ then L can only contain $4k,k \in \mathbb{N}$ ).

What is an upper-bound for related algorithms? I want to use the model in which operations on integers always take O(1). I can't use extra space (i.e. I can't build other trees). The tree isn't ordered in any way (it isn't a BST). My goal isn't to construct the tree but to verify that a given tree satisfies the property.

My thinking was: let's pick a complete balanced tree of n nodes. L nodes are n/2, as R nodes. If I have to verify that the content of a L node is multiple of R nodes, in the worst case I have to compute (L node) mod (every R node), hoping one of them is zero. For every node I have to make as many computations as the number of R nodes (-> n/2). To check the property for every L node the computations are (n/2 * n/2), so I would assume $n^2$ as an upper bound.

Is it correct?

Comment: As you said it would be O(n^2). There's nothing wrong. I thought of optimizing it.

Comment: 1) Which way is it now? The blockquote and the paragraph after disagree. 2) What are "related algorithms"? You can do many things on trees. 3) Does the property have to hold recursively? 4) Your upper bound is certainly correct; that much is elementary. Are you asking if it can be done faster?